# How to test custom Object via @JsonTest in Spring?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have my DeskDTO class that I have to test (guess I should). I found this toutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/testing-data-transfer-object-and-rest-controllers on internet but there is no explanation how to test custom class which my main class contains. To be clear:

My DeskDTO:

```
public class DeskDTO {

    private Long deskId;
    private String deskNumber;
    private String additionalNote;
    private LocalizationDTO localization;
    private Set<ElectronicEquipmentDTO> electronicEquipments;
```

My test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ReliceApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DeskDTOTest {

    private JacksonTester<DeskDTO> jacksonTester;

    private static final String DESK_NUMBER = "4-124";
    private static final String ADDITIONAL_NOTE = "Very good desk";
    private static LocalizationDTO localization;
    private static Set<ElectronicEquipmentDTO> electronicEquipments;

    private DeskDTO deskDTO;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws ParseException { //yes I know Im noob, Im still learning
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JacksonTester.initFields(this, objectMapper);

        BuildingDTO buildingDTO = new BuildingDTO();
        buildingDTO.setNameOfBuilding("Building D");

        FloorDTO floorDTO = new FloorDTO();
        floorDTO.setFloorNumber(4);
        floorDTO.setBuilding(buildingDTO);

        localization = new LocalizationDTO();
        localization.setFloor(floorDTO);
        localization.setxAxis(5);
        localization.setyAxis(6);

        ElectronicEquipmentDTO electronicEquipment = new ElectronicEquipmentDTO();
        electronicEquipment.setAdditionalNote("Nice laptop");
        electronicEquipment.setType(ElectronicEquipmentType.PC);
        electronicEquipment.setClient("Lufthansa");
        electronicEquipment.setExternalId("WS-1234");
        electronicEquipment.setLocalization(localization);

        electronicEquipments = new HashSet<>();
        electronicEquipments.add(electronicEquipment); 

        deskDTO = new DeskDTO(DESK_NUMBER, ADDITIONAL_NOTE, localization, electronicEquipments);
    }

    private <T> T asParsedJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(object);
        return JsonPath.read(json, "$");
    }

    @Test //this is working
    public void setDeskNumberSerializes() throws IOException {
        assertThat(this.jacksonTester.write(deskDTO))
                .extractingJsonPathStringValue("@.deskNumber")
                .isEqualTo(DESK_NUMBER);
    }

    @Test //same
    public void setAdditionalNoteSerializes() throws IOException {
        assertThat(this.jacksonTester.write(deskDTO))
                .extractingJsonPathStringValue("@.additionalNote")
                .isEqualTo(ADDITIONAL_NOTE);
    }

    @Test //this does not work
    public void setLocalizationSerializes() throws IOException {
        assertThat(this.jacksonTester.write(deskDTO))
                .extractingJsonPathStringValue("@.localization")
                .isEqualTo(localization);

    }

    @Test //this set does not work either
    public void setElectronicEquipmentsSerializes() throws IOException {
        assertThat(this.jacksonTester.write(deskDTO))
                .extractingJsonPathArrayValue("@.electronicEquipments")
                .isEqualTo(electronicEquipments);
    }
}
```

When I am using .extractingJsonPathStringValue I've got:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected a string at JSON path "@.localization" but found: {floor={floorId=null, floorNumber=4, building={buildingId=null, nameOfBuilding=Building D}}, xAxis=5, yAxis=6}
```

and when I am using .extractingJsonPathMapValue I've got:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expecting:
 <{"floor"={"building"={"buildingId"=null, "nameOfBuilding"="Building D"}, "floorId"=null, "floorNumber"=4}, "xAxis"=5, "yAxis"=6}>
to be equal to:
 <com.mrfisherman.relice.Dto.LocalizationDTO@2aafa84f>
but was not.
Expected :com.mrfisherman.relice.Dto.LocalizationDTO@2aafa84f
Actual   :{floor={floorId=null, floorNumber=4, building={buildingId=null, nameOfBuilding=Building D}}, xAxis=5, yAxis=6}
```

Comment: what is `JacksonTester<T>`?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/json/JacksonTester.html

Comment: `.extractingJsonPathStringValue("@.localization")` this returns a `String` value, then you are trying to compare this using `isEqualTo` to an `Object`. You can't compare a `String`, with an `Object`, you compare `String` with `String`.

Comment: then how to compare these two?

Comment: if you want to compare json strings you could use `objectMapper.#writeValueAsString` to convert the object to a json string and then compare the strings